# Importing PyMol modules into python program in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, protein-database, pymol

Hi I'm a complete beginner with Python and PyMol, but I've done a lot of work in Java. I am trying to import pymol modules(i think they're called modules or libraries) into my python program in Eclipse, but I keep getting the error "No module named 'pymol'". Is there some code that I need to add to import pymol or do i need to change some path variables or something... I want to make sure this code can run on other computers too, so hopefully the solution to my problem will just be extra code and not going into my system and changing variables or paths.

Comment: also i want to be able to make the script open up the pymol GUI thingie by itself... i dont want to have to go into the pymol command line to run the script (if possible... If doing this is too hard for a beginner like me, I'll just go into the pymol command line and run the script)

Comment: If you need to add additional information, it is better if you click 'edit' and add it into the question, rather than leaving it as a comment. Comments are small and not everyone reads them!